# yyless triggers signed comparison warning when generated scanner is compiled with -Wsign-compare

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I am having trouble with one of my lex (flex 2.6.0) scanner rules, it looks like:

```
. {
  /* Place the char back and process statment normally. */
  yyless(0);
  yycolumn--;
  BEGIN(CONDITION_NORMAL);
}
```

The trouble comes from the macro yyless(0) which expands to:

```
do {
 int yyl;
 for ( yyl = n; yyl < yyleng; ++yyl )
   if ( yytext[yyl] == '\n' )
     --yylineno;
}while(0)
```

The trouble is that yyleng is an unsigned type. In the project
I am working on, we have the gcc compiler flag to convert warnings
to errors so the signed/unsigned comparison warning gets flagged and
I get an error on compile.

Does anyone know if lex has a way of overriding macros or changing
types (yyleng to int)?

EDIT: (clarification)
We need to have a solution that does not modify the generated file in anyway after Lex has created it. Of course, I could go add a cast to the generated file, but that would cause trouble in the future if someone changed the lexer.

Comment: s/int yyl;/unsigned yyl;/ should probably do the trick (does it *need to be signed* (is -1 used as a sentinel value?)

Comment: @wildplasser: It does not need to be signed and I am reasonably convinced that a negative number as an argument to `yyless` would be a bug, since it would attempt to reset the input pointer to prior to the current token, which could be outside of the input buffer if the buffer was refilled during the scan of the current token. However, it will not suffice to fix only that use of `int`; there is another one a few lines further on which also needs to be changed. (You can see the problem in the quoted loop; if `n` were `-1`, that would examine `yytext[-1]` which could well be out of bounds.)

Comment: Well: then rewrite the skeleton file!

Comment: @wildplasser: yes, that is what the patch in the bug report linked from my answer does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official policy of the flex maintainers is that `-Werror` is not supported. (I quote: "...a compiler's warnings are not flex's bugs. In particular, "gcc -Werror" will probably fail.")

Nonetheless, I sympathize with this bug report, and I've filed it as such (https://sourceforge.net/p/flex/bugs/201/)

The simplest fix would be to apply the patch in that bug report to your copy of flex and rebuild it. If your approach to software distribution is to distribute the generated files, that (plus a note about the issue) should suffice, although I agree it is not ideal.

If you want an ugly workaround, you could try adding `-DYY_TYPEDEF_YY_SIZE_T -Dyy_size_t=ssize_t` to your compiler flags while compiling the generated scanner file. I didn't try that; if you do and it doesn't work, let me know. (I don't think it is correct to make `yy_size_t` a signed type, but it might squelch the warning, and it shouldn't hurt.)

Comment: The solution of adding the flags `-DYY_TYPEDEF_YY_SIZE_T -Dyy_size_t=ssize_t` did work for that singular issue, however there were other variables where the signed/unsigned warning would pop up. What I ended up doing to solve the problem was to add `-Wno-sign-compare` which I actually should have known to do before asking this question, but hey, now I know something about flex which I didn't before. Thank you!

Comment: @cramja: A number of signed comparison issues were fixed for release 2.6.0 (but not the one in yyless). It would be interesting to know if upgrading to 2.6.0 and using those defines "solved" the problem. But of course "interesting" may not be sufficient to justify the work of testing :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy yyleng to a local variable, redefine yyleng as int in local scope and then assign the value.

Comment: I think what you are saying is to change the lexer file after it has been processed? In this case we make it hard to edit the lexer in the future. I have updated the question with a clarification about this.